# Как обратиться к кнопке через addEventListener

Tags: javascript

при обращении выдается ошибка **Uncaught ReferenceError: product__add is not defined**

**Html**

```
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
            </button>
```

**javascript**

```
product__add-to-cart-button.addEventListener('click', function(){
                        alert(1);
                    });
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.product__add-to-cart-button').addEventListener(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы не выбрали элемент из DOM дерева. что бы обращаться к элементу, его нужно сначала выбрать. 
Как это сделать есть несколько способов, о которых можно почитать здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Данный пример сработает только на первом элементе.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("product__add-to-cart-button")[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(1);
});
```

```html
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
```

Я подозреваю у вас таких кнопок будет несколько, посему рабочий вариант будет:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("product__add-to-cart-button")].forEach(item =>{
  item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    alert(`click on element ${e.target.innerText} ${item.dataset.sbProductName}`)
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">1
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">2
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">3
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">4
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">5
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">6
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
<button class="product__add-to-cart-button" data-sb-id-or-vendor-code="005" data-sb-product-name="Iphone 4" data-sb-product-price="7000" data-sb-product-quantity="1" data-sb-product-img="smartbasket/img/iphone-4.png">7
    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = document.querySelector('.product__add-to-cart-button');

if(!obj){
   console.log('Element not fined');
}else{
  obj.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(1);
   });
}
```